# opengl libraries for ubuntu running on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, opengl

I am having Ubuntu 10.04 running on VirtualBox. Guest additions are installed successfully.

But Guest additions do not provide the OpenGL library. To run open GL demo what needs to be installed.

Some google links suggest Mesa utils. By my understanding is Mesa utils do not use vbox drivers to achieve hardware acceleration.

Ubuntu 10.04 is running on VirtualBox and not on bare metal. The host comprise of Zx400 CPU with nvidia graphics driver. But this is not relevant since I would be using the vbox drivers provided by guest additions on VirtualBox.

In this scenario how do I get OpenGL libraries on Ubuntu?. (Specially I am looking for solution other than Mesa, since mesa has support only for VMware and not for VirtualBox)

How to get Opengl libraries which use vbox drivers for 3D hardware accleration??

---

As i already mentioned, ubuntu 10.04 is running on VirtualBox and not on bare metal. the host comprise of Zx400 CPU with nvidia graphics driver. but this is not relevant since i would be using the vbox drivers provided by guest additions on VirtualBox.

In this scenario how to i get OpenGL libraries on Ubuntu. (Especially i am looking for solution other than Mesa, since mesa has support only for VMware and not for VirtualBox

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information about your Ubuntu Host PC to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: 1) Why such an old version of Ubuntu?
2) What is your graphic card?
3) What is your PC/laptop?

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/533566/virtualbox-3d-acceleration-does-not-work